# webkitRequestFullscreen() changing viewport / dimensions of webpage on chrome on android

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas, html5-fullscreen

For an application, I need to send chrome on android into full-screen mode.

I know that I need to use the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), which involves calling `Element.webkitRequestFullscreen()`.

So, I call this on `document.body` as I want everything to be put into fullscreen mode and take advantage of all the phone screen.

---

**However** the problem is that the screen is resized/loses quality. This severely mucks up my application (which is drawing to a canvas for virtual reality) because I need all the resolution I can get!

To demonstrate the screen has been enlarged and lost drawable pixels, see this from the console of inspecting my phone:

```
window.innerWidth
980
window.innerHeight
1547
//now I enter full screen...
window.innerWidth
360
window.innerHeight
640
```

Clearly, `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are being reduced by something when entering fullscreen, but I can't figure out what.

---

I have tried different resizing of the canvas which is contained in the body but to no avail.

But what I thought would be the solution would be to add a [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and I also tried setting a definitive content width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, initial-scale=1">
```

but neither of these seemed to have **any** effect on the behaviour of the webpage, so I am not sure if I am placing them wrong (in the `<head>`) or if I have the syntax wrong, but they don't change anything.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Nawal See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Joe Iddon, in my case, I was able to get fullscreen canvas without the unwanted zooming by fullscreening the canvas itself rather than the html page:           document.getElementById("myCanvas").requestFullscreen();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (more of a workaround) was to turn my website, that I was opening in Chrome on my phone, into a Progressive Web App.

This is as simple as writing a short `manifest.json` file in the root directory then once the website is open in Chrome, tapping on "Add to Home Screen".

Now the `manifest.json` file has an option: `display: fullscreen`.

This does not reduce the working space resolution and was just the fix I needed.

Furthermore, considering my goal of a VR experience, it makes more sense for this to be a web app than a website that you have to fuss around with in Chrome.